# SCOPE_IDENTITY read back

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a system that has been running on Windows Server 2003 and SQL Server 2000 for a number of years without a problem. Recently I moved the system to Windows Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 R2 and have started get a very strange intermittent problems.

I am inserting a row into a table with an identity column and executing a select to retrieve the identity value. Most of the time this code works fine but at random intervals the identity isn't returned. Sometimes no row is found so `dr.Read` returns false, other times I get a row back but there is no identity column in it. I checked the database and the insert has succeeded, it's just that the identity isn't returned. There are no triggers on the table.

I also tried changing the SQL to:

```
INSERT INTO test (value) 
VALUES (100) 
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS 'identity' OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

in case I was running into the ['max degree of parallelism'](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019779) bug but that didn't help either.

Here is relevant code (slightly simplified for illustration):

```
Dim dr As SqlDataReader = Nothing
Dim objCommand As New SqlCommand
Dim oConn As New SqlConnection
Dim id as integer

oConn.ConnectionString = connStr 
oConn.open()

objCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES (100) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS 'identity'", oConn, tr)

try
    dr = objCommand.ExecuteReader
    If Not dr.Read Then
        Throw (New Exception("Could not read IDENTITY"))
    Else
        id = dr("identity")
    End If
Catch
    Throw
Finally            
    If Not dr Is Nothing Then dr.Close()
    oConn.close()
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you simply execute them as two separate statements?

```
objCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES (100); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS 'identity'", oConn, tr)
```

[SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) gives you "the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope."

Answer (score 0):

The other option on SQL Server 2008 R2 would be to use the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO test (value) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
VALUES (100)
```

This will output the `ID` of the row that was inserted - and that's the identity value you want.

From your code, you should be able to fetch that `ID` if you use `ExecuteScalar` (instead of `ExecuteReader`) and just convert the `object` type you get back to an `int`